# Rendering an image in Javascript from binary data sent by Websockets

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm struggling to use a Websocket client to display a binary (PNG) image that has been sent from my server endpoint.
Within my Javascript client, I've set my websocket as follows:

```
 function send_message() {
                websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
                websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
                websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
                    onOpen(evt)
                };
                websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
                     draw(evt);
                };
                websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
                    onError(evt)
                };
            }
```

And here is the draw method which I've found in several tutorials or SO Threads:

```
function draw(imgData){

                   if(event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer)
                    {

                        var bytearray = new Uint8Array(event.data);

                         var tempcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                            tempcanvas.height = 221;
                            tempcanvas.width = 430;
                        var tempcontext = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');

                        var imgdata = tempcontext.getImageData(0,0,430,221);

                        var imgdatalen = imgdata.data.length;

                        for(var i=8;i<imgdatalen;i++)
                        {
                            imgdata.data[i] = bytearray[i];
                        }

                        tempcontext.putImageData(imgdata,0,0);


                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                            img.height = 221;
                            img.width = 430;

                            var dataURL = tempcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                            img.setAttribute( 'src',dataURL);
                            elem = document.getElementById('output');
                            elem.appendChild(img);
                            elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + "<br />";  
                    }

}
```

Unfortunately, just a bunch of pixels square shaped are rendered. I also attach the output of my Javascript console to show what I've received over the network (actually I can see the following two GETs after a request.
[image]
Here is how I'm sending the image from the server side (Java):

```
@OnOpen  
 public void hello(Session session) {

    File fi = new File("D:\\www\\images\\picture.png");
    byte[] fileContent=null;
    try {


        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fi);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);

        session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buf);
        } 
         catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: May I ask why the `tempCanvas` dimensions differ from the `getImageData` coordinates?

Comment: Btw, you do not need to create an img object. Just append the canvas for output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well point #1 was a typo, I've edited my question.
I've also tried with  `document.body.appendChild(tempcanvas);` instead of creating an img object but the result stayed the same :-(

Comment: Hm, I see nothing obvious wrong in your code. How do you make sure that you're sending the correct data?

Comment: Well, I've updated the question to include also the Java Websocket endpoint, in case I can get help from Java users too....